# Question of topology

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that the image of nowhere dense set under a continuous mapping is nowhere dense?

Comment: No take $\mathbb{R}\to\{*\}$ be the constant map (here $\{*\}$ is a one point topological space). Then the image of $\{0\}$ (which is nowhere dense) is the whole space.

Comment: Consider a map from the reals to a point. This sends every non-empty set to the whole space

Comment: Here is a less obvious example where the source and the target have the same dimension : consider a space filling curve $c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ (there exist such a surjective continuous map). Consider now the map $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(x,y)\mapsto c(x)$. Then the image of $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Consider $f: \mathbb{R}\to \{0\}$ by $f(x) = 0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that $\mathbb{Z}$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but you are mapping to the entire topological space.

Answer (score 0):

Very false. The (uniformly) continuous [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ maps the nowhere dense Cantor set onto $[0,1]$. In fact we can have any compact metric space $X$ as the image of such a continuous map from a nowhere dense set. The Cantor fucntion is just a convenient concrete example of this.